# start EC2 instance with unformatted ephemeral drives?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm using ec2 Amazon AMI images, I've disabled cloudinit mounts but the ephemeral drives always contain an ext3 file system is there a way of having a new instance boot without any file system on the ephemeral drives?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your instance size. However, the [EC2 Instance Store documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStoreDeviceNames) says:

> SSD-based instance store volumes that support TRIM instruction are not pre-formatted with any file system.

This may be your best bet. There is also a table with what instances types and volumes are formatted and mounted.